# Get class from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm wondering how to change a variable inside an object in an ArrayList.

I have tried `myList.get(i);` but this returns an `<Object>` and I don't understand what to do this.

(Basically) What I have:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
Issue issue = new Issue();
list.add(issue);
```

What i want to access later, via the list:

```
issue.myString;
```

So to clarify, I have an instance of `class Issue` inside `ArrayList list`, and I want to change `issue.myString`

Comment: cast that object to `Issue` for example -> **((Issue)list.get(index)).myString**

Comment: Lol... I thought I tried that but apparently I had just messed up the parentheses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have (at least) two options.

## The list contains only issues

In that case, you can use a typed list:

```
List<Issue> list = new ArrayList<>();
Issue issue = new Issue();
list.add(issue);
```

This way, calls like `list.get(i)` will return an `Issue`.

## The list contains issues and other non-issue objects

```
List list = new ArrayList();
Issue issue = new Issue();
list.add(issue);
Object object = new Object();
list.add(object);
```

In that case, you'll have to check if the object is an `Issue` first.

```
Object rawItem = list.get(i);
if(rawItem instanceof Issue) {
    Issue issue = (Issue) rawItem;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a typed list:

```
ArrayList<Issue> list = new ArrayList<>();
Issue issue = new Issue();
list.add(issue);
```

now `list.get(i)` will return `<Issue>` and not just `<Object>`